# Why is this Coroutine for my Weapon Reloading not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code for a Weapon with reloading, and if I start to reload, switch to a different weapon, and the switch back to the weapon that should be reloading, The weapon doesn't reload, can't shoot, and will Display the AmmoDisplay of the previous weapons... any idea why? I tried setting the `IEnumerator` to `public`, but that didn't work either.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;

public class GunScript_SB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;
    public float impactForce = 30f;
    public float fireRate = 15f;

    public float maxAmmo = 10;
    private float currentAmmo;
    public float reloadTime = 3f;
    private bool isReloading = false;

    public Camera fpsCam;
    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    public GameObject impactEffect;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ammunitionDisplay;

    private float nextTimeToFire = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
    }

    void onEnable()
    {
        isReloading = false;
        AmmoDisplay();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isReloading)
            return;

        if (currentAmmo <= 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reload());
            return;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }

        if (ammunitionDisplay != null)
        {
            AmmoDisplay();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && currentAmmo < maxAmmo)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reload());
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator Reload()
    {
        isReloading = true;
        Debug.Log("Reloading...");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);

        currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
        isReloading = false;
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();
        currentAmmo--;

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
            }

            if (hit.rigidbody != null)
            {
                hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * impactForce);
            }

            GameObject impactGO = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
            Destroy(impactGO, 1f);
        }
    }

    void AmmoDisplay()
    {
        ammunitionDisplay.SetText(currentAmmo + " / " + maxAmmo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your coroutine could possibly still running after switching weapon. Add a referencing field and stop the coroutine before starting it again:

```html
private Coroutine reloadCoroutine;


if (reloadCoroutine != null){
  StopCoroutine(reloadCoroutine);
}

reloadCoroutine = StartCoroutine(Reload());
```

Comment: I dont know If I put the code in the wrong place, but no matter where I put it, it still doesnt work...